# Errors starting wso2server.sh on AIX IBM PASE

Tags: wso2

Whis is what I get after trying to start the wso2carbon-4.2.0

### help please....

```
cd /barj/WSO2/wso2carbon-4.2.0/bin/                                                                                              

wso2server.sh                                                                                                                    
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk60/64bit                                              
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /barj/WSO2/wso2carbon-4.2.0                                                           
[2014-05-19 14:43:06,951]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...                   
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,036]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : OS/400 V6R1M0, PowerPC 
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,037]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /QOpenSys/QIBM/ProdData/JavaVM/jdk60/64bit/jre                                                                                                          
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,037]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.6.0                  
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,038]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : IBM J9 VM 2.4,IBM Corporation                                                                                                                           
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,038]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /barj/WSO2/wso2carbon-4.2.0                                                                                                                             
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,038]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /barj/WSO2/wso2carbon-4.2.0/tmp                                                                                                                         
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,039]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : barj, en-US, America/Chicago                                                                                                                            
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,407]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.SystemValidator} -  Could not validate the system for configuration parameter : swap                                                                                                       
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,408]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.SystemValidator} -  Could not validate the system for configuration parameter : ulimit                                                                                                     
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,622]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The default keystore (wso2carbon.jks) is currently being used. To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.                                                                          
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,623]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  The running OS : OS/400 is not a tested Operating System for running WSO2 Carbon                                                                          
[2014-05-19 14:43:07,624]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  CPU speed (MHz): 0 of the system is below the recommended minimum speed :800                                                                              
[2014-05-19 14:43:14,357]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.scan.CarbonTomcatJarScanner} -  Failed to scan [{0}] from classloader hierarchy                                                                                                                       
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file                                                                            
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)                                                                             
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:151)                                                                        
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:150)                                                                        
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:87)                                                                         
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:84)                                                        
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:60)                                                    
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:95)                                                   
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:119)                                          
        at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:86)                                        
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.FileUrlJar.<init>(FileUrlJar.java:41)                                                     
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:34)                                                
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig$FragmentJarScannerCallback.scan(ContextConfig.java:2625)                    
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.scan.CarbonTomcatJarScanner.process(CarbonTomcatJarScanner.java:262)                       
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.scan.CarbonTomcatJarScanner.scan(CarbonTomcatJarScanner.java:229)                          
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1917)                         
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1268)                                          
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)                                      
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)                                      
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)                               
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)                                      
          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)                                     
          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)                                                  
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)                                       
          at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)                                       
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)                                                    
          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)                                                              
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:906)                                   
          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:929)                                       
          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738)                                                                                 
 [2014-05-19 14:43:14,700] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig} -  Failed to process JAR found at URL [jar:file:/barj/WSO2/wso2carbon-4.2.0/repository/components/plugins/jgroups_3.0.6.wso2v1.jar!/] for ServletContainerInitializers for context with name [/]                                                                                                                       
 [2014-05-19 14:43:14,746] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig} -  Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)                                                                                                                      
 [2014-05-19 14:43:14,787]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 268ms     
 [2014-05-19 14:43:15,796]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE                                                                                                                            
 [2014-05-19 14:43:16,338]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.                                                                                                            
 [2014-05-19 14:43:16,558]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined                                                                                                            
 [2014-05-19 14:43:16,848] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext} -  Error getConfigured                                
 [2014-05-19 14:43:16,858] ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext} -  Context [/] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: Seems, `/barj/WSO2/wso2carbon-4.2.0/repository/components/plugins/jgroups_3.0.6.wso2v1.jar` is corrupted. I can't be read. Get the fresh copy of product.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try deleting the following jar from the plugins directory and see?

jgroups_3.0.6.wso2v1.‌​jar